# New to texturing, how do i make my metal texture glossy?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I know some other people have asked this question but none of the answers to the other peoples questions have helped me resolve this issue. i am trying to make a metal cube...but it looks like this:

[image]

this was a 32 sample version because i did not have time to render it.
i used all 4 maps from my texture. don't know if that was a good idea.

it is too dark and odd looking i want it to look brighter like normal metal. any help is appreciated :) here is a .blend file:

Comment: This question is better asked in a site like the forums at Blender Artist.com. As asked, there are too many answers, too subject to the opinion of the one answering to be a good fit on this site.

Comment: i don't use blender artist though @brasshat

Comment: very poor mesh resolution, so the shading is poor quality. Either that or your lighting is causing it. Add a bevel modifier with angle limits.

Comment: @BlenderUser1 You can create an account at https://blenderartists.org, it is free, try it. This site is better suited for technical questions specifically about Blender, not artistic critique. Anyway, your maps are fine, it looks like your box has smooth shading, which is not adequate for flat faces. Either make it flat shaded, or add some bevels like VRM suggested. Maybe make your texture influence bump channel too, and add some context, like ground and some objects around it.

Comment: problem has been resolved, thank you for all those who have helped :)